# NoMethodError for CarrierWave current_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I can't call CarrierWave current_path in my custom class.

```
NoMethodError: private method `try' called for #<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007fadf259fbf8>



def send_letter(letter)
   data = {}
   data[:attachment]   = File.new("#{letter.template.attachment.current_path}", 'rb')
end
```

it's happened in letter.template.attachment.current_path call, and I don't understand why. In rails console the same command works great...  but when I'm trying to run it with rake task it fails with  NoMethodError (above). How can I get the path to the file instead of current_path (if it was upload using CarrierWave). Thx for your time!

UPDATE
Thx for your answer. letter.template.present? - true

letter.template.attachment.present? -true

letter.template.attachment.methods.respond_to?(:current_path‌​) - false

but letter.template.attachment.methods (there is :current_path)

:cache!, :cache_name, :retrieve_from_cache!, :cache_stored_file!, :sanitized_file, :model, :mounted_as, :to_s, :length, :size, :path, :read, :content_type, :identifier, :blank?, :current_path

Answer (score 0):

`NoMethodError` means that, well, there is no `attachment#current_path`

Is `letter.template.present?`, and is `letter.template.attachment.present?`, and does `letter.template.attachment.methods.respond_to?(:current_path)`

See what methods are available for `letter.template.attachment` by hitting `letter.template.attachment.methods`.

It looks like CarrierWave also overrides `try` — what's the trace look like for `send_letter`?

Comment: Updated my question